# How to install a TP-LINK network adapter?

Tags: networking, hardware, internet

How  can I install a TP-LINK network adapter?

I have 8 files for Linux driver they are: `compat.h`, `crc32.h`, `ethtool.h`, `Makefile`, `mii.c`, `mii.h`, `sundance_main.c` and `readme.txt`.

I am using [Zorin OS](http://zorin-os.com/free.html).

## I want to know how to install it?

Comment: What is the network adapter's model?

Comment: network adapter's model is TF-3200

Comment: just out of curiousity: is the  sundance module loaded and whats the dmesg output when it loads

Comment: Some vendors supply Linux drivers even though the required drivers have been in the kernel for ages. It is not necessary or even preferable to install them that way.

Answer (score 2):

At first shot I would copy (!) these 8 files into their own directory, open a terminal (your desktop environment should have a button somewhere that opens one), cd into that directory and run the command `make`. However, there is a high probability, that this will result in a lot of error which actually mean, that you are missing quite a bit of software.

Please consider:

There is a sundance driver in today's Linuxes which works quite well (also for me) and it's rather odd that you need to install (and even compile) a driver. Usually the only driver people sometimes install are proprietary graphics drivers. How did you come up with that idea? Further, where did you get the sources from?

If you really need to compile you have to have (at least) the zorin packages `build-essential`, `linux-kernel-headers` installed.

Comment: well is there any video tutorials regarding this?

Comment: What would you want to watch people while they are typing for?
What else do you need help with? Installing packages? Creating a directory? Copying files? Opening a terminal? Changing directories? Running make?

Comment: yes thats all ;)

Answer (score 0):

This antique should have been recognized automatically by Linux.

In case it wasn't, what happens when you type (in a Terminal):

```
sudo modprobe sundance
```

Comment: i dont know what Terminal is. Is zorin os has it?

Comment: Yes it does. You need to learn a bit about Linux before you can start debugging it. You can try to press Alt+F2. You may get asked which command you want run. If that's the case enter `xterm` and hit enter. Then you will get a terminal. Also if you click through the applications installed on your machine there has to be some thing called "terminal" or "xterm" or something with "terminal" in its name. If nothing works hit Ctrl+Alt+F2. There you should be able to log with your normal username and password and have a terminal.